# Sometimes provide option to install flash and sometimes not

Tags: java, html, flash, jsp, internet-explorer-8

In my web application i am facing a weird problem. In jsp there is code for Brightcove video player.  For playing this you need flash with Internet Explorer 8. While running this jsp page it sometimes provide the option to install flash and sometimes not. But what i want that every time it must show the option to install flash at the client side if the flash is not available. Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue of BrightCove player from your explanation.

I would suggest if there is an issue don't rely over it go for javascript flash plugin detection [here you go](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/plugindetect.shtml)

Comment: still the same issue.. after refreshing the page multiple time it provide the option to install flash player.

Comment: you have installed and  its showing to install it again. ? have you used javascript I have suggested ? I haven't used it but it seems promising